# Google Sheet - Count Random Average

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

```
Number Of Invoice |   From   |   To   | Total

       10         |   $25    |  $100  |   ?
```

I want the `Total` column to fill with the average number of 10 `invoice` with each invoice random between the `from` and `to` column.

Whats is the formula for that ?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to

***Get the sum/average of 10 randomly generated numbers between 25 and 100***

**For the average**

```
=AVERAGE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(SEQUENCE(100,1,25,1),100)),10,1))
```

**For the sum**

```
=SUM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(SEQUENCE(100,1,25,1),100)),10,1))
```

Comment: Welcome.
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thx for the help ~

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. Glad I could help.